# Why does the raywenderlich code break if you enable the scheme "-com. apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1"

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest, executefetchrequest

This example shows how to extract data asynchronously using coreData. If you run program without scheme  "-com. apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1" all work, but if you turn on scheme  "-com. apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1" we get runtime error.
Why this happens I don't know

(I'm not violating these terms)
From apple doc

> Core Data is designed to work in a multithreaded environment. However, not every object under the Core Data framework is thread safe. To use Core Data in a multithreaded environment, ensure that:

> Managed object contexts are bound to the thread (queue) that they are associated with upon initialization.

> Managed objects retrieved from a context are bound to the same queue that the context is bound to.

```
Stack Trace

CoreData`+[NSManagedObjectContext __Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__]:
    0x7fff23a8a65e <+0>: pushq  %rbp
    0x7fff23a8a65f <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
->  0x7fff23a8a662 <+4>: ud2 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
      let batchResult = try coreDataStack.managedContext.execute(batchUpdate) as! NSBatchUpdateResult
      print("Records updated \(batchResult.result!)")
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not update \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    let venueFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Venue> = Venue.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest = venueFetchRequest

    asyncFetchRequest = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest<Venue>(fetchRequest: venueFetchRequest) {
      [unowned self] (result: NSAsynchronousFetchResult) in
      guard let venues = result.finalResult else {
        return
      }

      self.venues = venues
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    do {
      guard let asyncFetchRequest = asyncFetchRequest else {
        return
      }
      try coreDataStack.managedContext.execute(asyncFetchRequest)
      // Returns immediately, cancel here if you want
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
 }
```

Comment: It might help if you could add a link to the project you're using.

Comment: @TomHarrington

download [link](https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/core-data-by-tutorials-source-code). Open “04-04-intermediate-fetching” -> final -> BubbleTeaFinder And necessarily add scheme “-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1”, and run the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good catch. I wish the answer helped more though.

I downloaded the code and tried it out, and after messing with it for a bit I'm pretty sure that this is a bug in Apple's frameworks. It looks like the code in the sample project is correct, but the concurrency check flags it anyway. I don't know if this is because the code actually causes a concurrency violation or if there's no violation but the flag is buggy.

What you're seeing is unfortunately just what happens right now, and it's not fixable in an app-- only Apple can resolve it. It's also a longstanding issue, as you can see from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42433977/43832) from a few years ago. I suggest filing a [bug with Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/).